# Position a chip within CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, chips

I am trying to position a `Chip` in the top right of a `CircleAvatar` similar to the below, but cant seem to be able to move it

[image]

```
SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 50,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: const [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: Chip(
                                      label: Text('7'),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        width: 1,
                                      )),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

The above code is producing this
[image]

Comment: user [this](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package

Comment: yeah we dont want to use a 3rd package but thanks

Comment: I copied your code but cannot reproduce the problem. For me the number is at the top right corner.

Comment: @BossNass refer my [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74951515/13997210) I have try without 3rd package hope its help to you

Comment: It seems like this happens in Android but not in web. I have not tested iOS or desktop yet.

Comment: It seems like that different platforms force the size of the chip differently. You can read more here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/materialTapTargetSize.html. According to that, this answer seems best https://stackoverflow.com/a/74951502/14493188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require nested `Stack` and you are missing the heirarchy in placing the widgets. And set `materialTapTargetSize` to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` which will remove the default padding around the chip. And force it to shrink to its size

Mistake in your code:

```
Stack
 | CircularAvatar
   | Stack          <-- Not needed
     | Align
```

Correct code:

```
Stack
  | CircularAvatar
  | Align           <-- Should be in same hierarchy as CircularAvatar
```

Try the following code:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: const [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              radius: 50,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.KZ9jKGoLM_wXMX6aHCB6oAHaEY?pid=ImgDet&rs=1'),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Chip(
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                label: Text(
                  '78',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are right that there is no need for the stack inside the stack but in this case it does not affect the end result.

Comment: For text to be added below is it best to wrap this into a column and then add text

Comment: Add `Text` as a sibling to `SizedBox` and wrap these both in `Column`

Answer (score 1):

By setting `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` on `Chip` widget you force it to take as little space as it needs.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: Stack(
    children: const [
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Chip(
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          label: Text('7'),
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(child: FlutterLogo(),),
        new Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 15,
              minHeight: 15,
            ),
            child: new Text('11',
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 11,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for a nested stack to achieve this. I simply wrapped the `Chip` in a `FittedBox` and then the `FittedBox` in a `SizedBox`. The thing to understand here is that the `CircleAvatar` has to be smaller than the main `SizedBox` and the `Chip` has to be smaller than the `CircleAvatar` in order for these to be stacked properly.
For that I've used three variables where `mainSize` is the size of the main `SizedBox`, `radius` is the radius of the `CircleAvatar` and it is two third of the `mainSize`, `avatarSize` is the size of the `SizedBox` containing the `Chip` and is one half of the `radius` (or one third of the `mainSize`).

Here is the revised code:

```
double mainSize = 50;
double radius = mainSize * 2 / 3;
double avatarSize = radius / 2;

SizedBox(
            width: mainSize,
            height: mainSize,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: radius,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                  child: Text('BN'),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: avatarSize,
                    height: avatarSize,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Chip(
                        label: Text('17'),
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Hope it helps!